# Change a data frame in an outer scope in a function

Tags: r

In `fun_outer` I created an empty data frame `df`, and I want to add a new row to `df` via the inner function `fun_inner`:

```
fun_outer <- function() {
  df <- data.frame()
  fun_inner()
  return(df)
}

fun_inner <- function(){
  tmp <- data.frame(x = 1 ,y = 2)
  df <<- rbind(df, tmp)
}
```

I would expect that executing `fun_outer()` could return a `df` like:

```
  x   y
  1   2
```

But I actually got an error:

```
Error in rep_len(xi, nvar) (temp.R#355): attempt to replicate non-vector
```

Then I tried another approach:

```
fun_outer <- function() {
  df <- data.frame()
  fun_inner(df)
  return(df)
}

fun_inner <- function(x){
  tmp <- data.frame(x = 1 ,y = 2)
  df <<- rbind(x, tmp)
}
```

And this time by executing `fun_outer()` I got another error:

```
Error in fun_inner(df) (temp.R#344): cannot change value of locked binding for 'df'
```

How can I create a data frame in an outer function, and bind row(s) to it using an inner scope function?

My intention was to use an iterator function inside a function `A` to append new data from each iteration to a data frame created inside function `A`

Comment: R is a [lexically scoped language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#R)) which mean you can access by name only variables defined within definition scope, not within execution scope. In general programming, <<- assignment is preferable to be avoided, as it could lead to unexpected behaviour. It is better to be used only for functions that return closures, to save state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a variable cannot be found in the current function it is looked up in the environment where the function was defined, not the environment from which it was called.  `<<-` works the same way.  What you want is the parent frame which is the caller.

```
fun_outer <- function() {
  df <- data.frame()
  fun_inner()
  return(df)
}

fun_inner <- function(envir = parent.frame()){
  tmp <- data.frame(x = 1 ,y = 2)
  envir$df <- rbind(envir$df, tmp)
}

fun_outer()
##   x y
## 1 1 2
```

Comment: Does it work with iterator function? If I call `fun_inner()` inside `fun_inner()`, then I think parent.frame() will not give `df` defined in `fun_outer()`?

Comment: You can call the inner function using the environment where `df` is defined. That is why it was made an argument.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out: when calling `fun_inner()` inside `fun_inner()`, use `fun_inner(envir = envir)` and this will ensure all the `fun_inner()` calls can modify `df` in the same enviroment, where `df` is defined